# Boost libraries and multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, clang, preprocessor-directive

I'm looking for clarification/gotchas on using the **Boost libraries that are header-only in a multi-threaded environment**.

As these don't require the Boost libraries to be built/linked against the project but just need to be dropped into the project I'm a huge fan..

However, using a number of Boost libraries in a heavily multi-threaded environment I was looking for guidance on safe usage under these circumstances.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any clear guidelines in the Boost documentation.
So I suppose the question basically is:

Are there any preprocessor macros - i.e. `BOOST_...` - that must be used (or are highly recommended) when using the Boost header-only libraries in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Although somewhat redundant these days (since C++ 11 adopted them natively), the Boost smart pointers package allowed you to define macros indicating whether or not you were using them in a multithreaded environment. If you weren't multithreaded, the effect was to remove the use of semaphores or atomics in the smart pointers, as they'd not be necessary. This saved a bit of time. The default was "multithreaded". It's possible this is a common theme across all the Boost libraries.

Comment: There is nothing like that that is global to the entire Boost set of libraries. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @bazza When non compiling for MT, a decent compiler should be able to remove at least some MT primitives; although some MT oriented tools can also be used w/o threads...

Comment: @rustyx, I can't be more specific because I don't know what other Boost libraries have done in this regard, if anything! They may have implemented something similar, but I don't know. Given the dearth of answers following this theme, I suspect they haven't. But Boost smart pointers definitely do have macros used to indicate a non-multithreaded environment (as I say the default was assumed to be multithreaded).

Comment: For Boost smart pointers there the macros BOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS  (says that the application isn't multi-threaded) and  BOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS (says that pthread semaphores should be use). Without either the library will default to assuming multithreaded and will use whatever lock method is relevant to the platform. On some platforms that will be pthreads semaphores. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety